# How best to reduce CPU time used by a datastore put

Tags: google-app-engine, optimization, datastore

I have a cron job which I run every three minutes, which pulls some data from a remote API, and then stores it in my local datastore. However, this is taking a huge amount of CPU time  in the datastore put operation. I suspect I'm probably doing something really stupid which can be optimised a lot:

```
result = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
foos = json.loads(result)['foo']
bars = json.loads(result)['bar']

models = []
for foo in foos:
    d = FooContainer()
    d.Property = foo.Value #in real code, this is setting a load of values based off foo     
    models.append(d)

for bar in bars:
    d = BarContainer()
    d.Property = bar.Value #in real code, this is setting a load of properties based off bar
    models.append(d)

db.put(models)
```

As you can see, I'm storing every piece of data returned as a new "row" in my local datastore tables. Is there some technique I can use to reduce the huge datastore CPU time used by this cron job?

Comment: How many entities are you saving?

Comment: the latest job saved 217 foos and 137 bars. Most jobs will be roughly the same size

Answer (score 6, accepted):

~2k cpu_ms looks about right. You are seeing 46k `api` cpu_ms because the datastore can only write max. 10 entities per second (governed by the api), and you are writing 450+ entities, thus `450+/10` is around 46k cpu_ms.

The `api` usage doesn't count directly against the bottom line of your quota, only the `real` ~2k will. So don't worry about it, you're just fine.

Comment: So although the appengine console is warning me that I'm using an average of 59070 for every time this cron job runs, it really doesn't matter all that much?

Comment: Notice in your output you have `real` and `api`. `real` is counted against your quota. `real` is the actual cpu work that is done, measured in milliseconds against an imaginary 1.2GHz cpu (see appengine docs for details on this). Now if you find that `real` is something like 59k+ cpu_ms, then you have a problem, but you're only at ~2k, and that's every 3 minutes, so this routine is only going to use a small fraction of your free quota.

Answer (score 1):

The put is fine. Really the only way you can get a put wrong is to use too many RPCs. You're already using just one.

Storing ~400 entities in one request handler is going to be expensive. If you're looking to optimize, I would ask yourself whether you really need to store that many entities at once. Could you run the cron job more frequently and return smaller batches? Do you actually need one entity per row, or could you accomplish the same thing with fewer entities and a ListProperty? There isn't really enough context in your question to offer actionable advice, but it's something to consider.

Answer (score -7):

Have you tried using `nice` to be nice to others process?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29

Also, be sure you are doing bulk insert but it seems so.

Comment: Does nice apply to appengine?

Comment: The app engine has no notion of "niceness". Horrible answer.